# how are default parameter values handled in scriptine?

Tags: python, scriptine

I have figured out that one can use `scriptine` in the following way:

```
import scriptine

def test_command(x,y):
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    print '{0} + {1} = {2}'.format(x, y, x + y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scriptine.run()
```

If I execute in the command line:

```
python my_script.py test 10 20
```

I get the following result:

```
10 + 20 = 30
```

So, important thing is to define a function that ends with `_command`. Then I call the script using the function name without `_command` and the following values will be interpreted as argument of the function.

On of the things is not clear to me is how default values are interpreted. For example, if in the definition of the function I write `test_command(x = 100, y = 200)` and then I used the above mentioned command `python my_script.py test 10 20`, I get `100 + 200 = 300`. In other words, default values of the argument are used in spite on the fact that I gave values of the variables.

Can anybody explain what is happening there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the first example [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scriptine/0.2.0a2) values for parameters with defaut values shoudl be prefixed with `--`:

```
 def example_command(name, countdown=False, repeat=10):
    ...


 python test.py example Pete --countdown --repeat 5
```